# Continuity Conditions

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

A function f(x) is said  be continuous at a if the following three conditions hold: 
 1) $\lim_{x \to  a} f(x)$ exits
 2) $ f(a)$ is defined
 3)  $\lim_{x \to  a} f(x)$ =f(a)

Can we find an example for a case where condition  1 and 2 are met but condition 3 is violated so that it ended up making function not continuous ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually really straightforward :  to find an example 
take any continuous function (let's say $f$) at any point $k$.

then what you do is you define 
$$\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
&g(x)=f(x) \,\forall x\neq k  \\ 
&g(k)=a \\ 
&\forall a\neq f(k)
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

This actually works for all $f$ continuous at point $k$

For example let's say $f(x)=x^3-x.$ at point $k=3, f$ is continuous, and $f(3)=24$.
We'll just set, according to what is said above : $$\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
&g(x)=f(x) \,\forall x\neq 3  \\ 
&g(3)=1\neq 24\\ 
\end{aligned} \right.$$

$g(3)$ is defined,  $\lim_{x\to 3} g(x)=24$ exists, but 
$$g(3)=1\neq \lim_{x\to 3} g(x)$$
Hence $g$ is not continuous at 3

It is however continuous for every other point in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Pick any continuos function $f$ and define
$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
f(x) &\hbox{if $x \neq a$}\\
f(a)+1 &\hbox{if $x=a$}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $g$ is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^2-1}{x-1} & x \neq 1\\
0 & x = 1\end{cases}$$

Now, it is easily checked that (1) and (2) are satisfied and (3) is violated as asked for.

Comment: It's better to give some elaborations about properties (1), (2) and (3). -- from [Review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1007132).