# In the Staircase paradox, where does the limit function differ from the hypothenuse?

Tags: geometry, limits, paradoxes

I am aware of the answers to the [Staircase paradox](https://thephilosophyforum.com/discussion/7842/the-diagonal-or-staircase-paradox) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/the-staircase-paradox-or-why-pi-ne4)

Now for the example of the unit square and the approximation of the hypothenuse by the staircase function, surely the limit function differs from the hypothenuse in some way, hence the differing lengths.

What is a characterisation of the points where these differ ?

Comment: There is the limiting of the staircases, and the limiting of the lengths of the staircases. In this process, and using the standard notions of distance and such associated with the process, the limit of the staircases exists and equals the hypothenuse while the limit of the lengths of the staircases exists but is not equal to the length of the hypothenuse. All this means is that the function that assigns "length" to these geometrical curves is **not a continuous function** (more precisely, condition *3)* [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2767663/13130) for continuity fails).

Comment: See [The staircase paradox, or why $\pi\ne4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/12906/13130) and [What is the history of staircase or =4 paradox?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/11240/264)

Comment: many thanks for your help !

Comment: A characterization of the points where they differ is that the "paradox" version connects points that aren't on the arc or line being measured. The "right" one connects points on the arc/line.